# C++: Construct a vector of Box types from vector of boxed elements

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, boxing

The following is a simplified excerpt of my type system:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Box {
public:
    Box(const T& value) : _value(value) {};
    T _value;
};

template <class T>
class Vector : protected std::vector<T> {
public:
    Vector() {}
    Vector(const std::vector<T>& values) { /* ...*/ }
    using std::vector<T>::push_back;
};

typedef Box<int> Int;
typedef Box<std::string> String;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Vector<Int> v1;
    v1.push_back(Int(0));

    std::vector<String> strings2 = { String("a"), String("b") };
    Vector<String> v2(strings2);

    std::vector<std::string> strings3 = { "a", "b" };    
    // The following does not compile, since strings3 elements
    // are of the sub type
    Vector<String> v3(strings3);
}
```

**How to define a constructor which allows the last line to compile?**

Of course for this small code example there might be better designs for `Vector` and `Box` but the types here are over-simplified.

Comment: You probably want something like that `template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, U>::value>* = nullptr>
    Vector(const std::vector<U>& values);`

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. Why are the C++ experts here always so humble that they never post their working suggestions as answer but as comment? :-) Do so, if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a template constructor:

```
template <typename U,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, U>::value>* = nullptr> 
Vector(const std::vector<U>& values);
```